# Mod rewrite pass multiple parameters without directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect https://www.example.com/test/track.gif?par1=1&par2=2&par3=3 to https://www.example.com/test/track.php?par1=1&par2=2&par3=3. 
This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^test/track\.gif(.*)(.*)(.*)$ test/track.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3 [NC,L]
```

Which doesn't work. If there was directories between it would be easy, but I am not sure how I can pass parameters without directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found answer:

```
RewriteRule ^test/track\.gif$ test/track.php [NC,L]
```

Now all parameters will be passed to track.php and can be accessed with $_GET variable.